# How to copy a typed class into a dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic, servicestack

I would like to take a typed class, copy it to a dynamic object, add an arbitrary value, then serialize it to a json object using the ServiceStack JSON converter. Something like this:

```
dynamic toAddTo = new ExpandoObject();
toAddTo.CloneFrom(model);
toAddTo.arbitratyValue = "Fancy Things";
return jsonApiType.ToJson();
```

Has anybody done something that will work for that in a performant way?

Comment: I assume you're looking for an implementation of `CloneFrom`.  Try [this link](http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/06/converting-any-object-to-dynamic.html)

Comment: I was curious if it is baked into the CLR in some way I'm not aware of or if there's an existing, widely used library that does this already. That link is helpful though. Thank you!

Comment: @jereme While it is possible to copy the **value** of properties/fields to an `ExpandoObject`, this won't copy methods, and it is probably impossible to do it.

Comment: I'm not concerned about methods, just public properties. The link from D Stanley accomplishes what I want to do; I was hoping for something I could add from nuget or was already in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to add properties to `ExpandoObject` individually.  If the source object is static and the number of properties isn't too large you could create an anonymous type:

```
var jsonApiType = new {
    model.Name,
    model.Age, 
    ...
    arbitratyValue = "Fancy Things"
};

return jsonApiType.ToJson();
```

or you could wrap your model:

```
var jsonApiType = new {
    model,
    arbitratyValue = "Fancy Things"
};

return jsonApiType.ToJson();
```

but that changes the resulting JOSN, and I suspect you're looking for a "clever" way to add a property to your json that doesn't exist in your model.

Comment: Exactly. The link D Stanley posted above works for what I want to do.